# You are my dismay

Tags: word-choice, nouns

*Dismay*, as a noun, means:

> Consternation and distress, typically that caused by something unexpected.

Is it correct to say that something *is my dismay*, (Rather than something *happened in my dismay*)? For example, would the following be correct:

> The mentor abandoned me. He *is my dismay*.

(As in, the mentor caused me to be distressed).

Would saying that something *is your dismay* be correct, or how would you go about saying such thing?

Comment: I think it'd be better to say, "He filled me with dismay."

Comment: "I will be graduating dismay" :)

Comment: @JeffSahol Hmm. Dismay be a wrong answer.

Comment: @JeffSahol- I graduated in disember.

Comment: Just to nitpick, *happened in my dismay* is just as incorrect as *is my dismay*. The idiom is ***to*** *my dismay*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't sound like something a native English speaker would say.

You could say: *The mentor abandoned me. He is one of my stressors.* Or you could say, *Much to my dismay, the mentor abandoned me.*

One more thing: people usually say things happen *to my dismay* not *in my dismay.* You could, I suppose, say *"In my dismay, I wrote a sad poem."* But otherwise, stick with "to my dismay."

Comment: I'm going to upvote, but only because I really like "Much to my dismay..." (I'm not all that fond of "He is one of my stressors" – but I'll not let that offset my upvote.)

Comment: @J.R. I'm not fond of it, either. :) I was just trying to think of a way to somewhat preserve the OP's original sentence.

Answer (score 6):

Basically: no. We would normally say, "The mentor abandoned me. He caused me dismay." Or, "He caused me to feel dismay." That is, "dismay" is a feeling. You would not say that a person or an event IS dismay; you say they "made me feel dismay".

Think of it like other words for feelings, like "anger". You wouldn't normally say, "Roger cheated me. He is my anger." You would say, "He caused my anger" or "He caused me to become angry."

(You might say something like "He is my dismay" in a song or a poem. But then you are being metaphorical.)

Comment: I really liked your analogy and then I realized that *joy* like *anger* is a feeling, and we often say of loved ones e.g. children, "They are my (pride and) joy".

Comment: @Mari-LouA True. I think that's more an idiom then a literal use of the words though. Note that one would not normally say, "My son Bob is my pride" or "My son Bob is my joy". It's always, "... my pride and joy." The fact that it only makes sense when the specific combination of words is used is pretty much the definition of an idiom.